# Startapp django : does not create files

Tags: python, django

I get a problem trying to create a new app with django ...
when i use python manage.py startapp newapp
i get no error and the folder newapp is created but there no file in it at all ?!

it suposed to create some file minimun **init**.py

Regards

Comment: Try using `django-admin.py startapp newapp`

Comment: Well, show us the error

Comment: Can you mention your exact steps, including information regarding your os, your python version, django version and if this is the first time you tried creating a new app or not?

Comment: I tryed using django-admin.py startapp newapp i ve got the same result I am using python 2.7.3 django 1.5.4 in windows xp and it s my first use of this command

there no Error the command seems to run and the folder is created but there no file in it

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
$ python path/to/django-admin.py startapp app_name
```

I'm not sure why that has never been changed in the documentation, but calling startapp using manage.py hasn't worked for me since 2008.